# PHP/CSS How to achieve a checkerboard style

Tags: php, css

I'm trying to achieve the following using PHP and CSS:

```
1 0 1 0
0 1 0 1
1 0 1 0
0 1 0 1
```

Using a single class, so 1 will be the class of dark and 0 the class of light.

Below is what I'm trying to create:

[image]

I've managed to achieve this using the nth-child selectors but isn't great, especially as more are added.

I'm using WordPress and the amount of blocks will be based on the amount of posts under a custom post type, currently there are 20 but this will increase.

Simplified Example:

```css
.wrap{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: 300px;
}
.checker{
  background-color: rgba(43,55,140,.8);
}
.checker:nth-child(n+2):nth-child(even):nth-child(-n+4),
.checker:nth-child(n+5):nth-child(odd):nth-child(-n+8),
.checker:nth-child(n+9):nth-child(even):nth-child(-n+12){
  background-color: rgba(181,230,254,.8);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="checker"></div>
    <div class="checker"></div>
    <div class="checker"></div>
    <div class="checker"></div>
    <div class="checker"></div>
    <div class="checker"></div>
    <div class="checker"></div>
    <div class="checker"></div>
    <div class="checker"></div>
    <div class="checker"></div>
    <div class="checker"></div>
    <div class="checker"></div>
</div>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the simplest way to achieve this would be to insert an empty element after every 4th div.

This would allow you to generate a chess-board like colouring by simply using `:nth-child(odd)`

I don't use PHP, but presumably there is a modulo operator available. The code might look something like this:

```
if ($i % 5 == 0) {
   // Create empty element.
}
```

Example:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.container > div {
  width: 25%;
  padding-top: 25%;
  background: lightblue;
}

.container > div:nth-child(odd) {
  background: blue;
}

.container > .empty {
  width: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div class="empty"></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div class="empty"></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div class="empty"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

(On phone so apologies for description sans code).

Not experienced with WordPress, but the code doesn’t seem to specify a fixed number of elements per row (since you’re using bootstrap styles).

Now, it’d simple if you knew the number of elements per row, since you can just nth-child that quite succinctly.

For example, suppose it’s 4 elements per row.  Then 8n, 8n+1, 8n+3, and 8n+6 are dark, which you can verify visually.

Of course in responsive we do not necessarily know how wide a row will be.  But!  You’re using bootstrap styles, so you do know (with caveats) since you know the media queries for when you switch from col-md-4 to col-xs-12, for example.

So, my thought is to have a set of nth child rules for each such breakpoint.

### EDIT

In general, if a row is x elements wide, 2x+y rules are an easy way to make a checkboard using nth-child rules when the elements/divs themselves have no particular organization.